# I am a volleyball player and I need better endurance. Please help!

Tags: training, volleyball

Okay. I play volleyball in Southern California. I consider myself a high level athlete but there is a problem (or what I think is a problem). I know this is kind of silly but whenever I take private lessons with my coach I get exhausted and I literally AM ALL OVER THE PLACE. The constant approach, jump, hit, pull back out and repeat. The serving, the constant shuffling. It wears me out. All of the other girls that take privates don't get tired like I do or as fast as I do. Like when I jump to hit my vertical gets smaller and smaller as the private goes through and it's really frustrating and it's making think I'm not doing good. It's degrading. I want to play college ball so bad but sometimes I think I'm not good enough because I can't even have enough endurance to last a private for an hour!

Comment: On this site maybe it is better to ask in [Physical Fitness section](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volleyball)

Comment: It's just a basic advice, but sometimes it's good to think "outside the box". Endurance can sometimes be related to lifestyle hygiene (sleep hours, nutrition, bad habits...).

Answer (score 6):

The obvious answer here is "ask your coach". If they can't tell you how to be a better athlete, then they're not the right coach *for you* no matter how good their technical volleyball coaching might be.